# NAs introduced by coercion error on Numeric Data Frame

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I am trying to cluster a Data Frame but when I run the dist Function I get the error "NAs introduced by coercion".

[image: Error message]

At first I thought if was becuase my DF contained factor vectors, like this:

[image: Data Frame]

but I then made a new DF with just numeric values and had the same error message:

[image: New DF]

So I am not sure why I am getting this error message, what is it I am not seeing ?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? And I highly recomend giving the code in text and not in a png.

Comment: Sure I am running the the following command :  `code` distances = dist(imputedTrainNoQuestions[, 2:5], method = "euclidean") `code`   on my dafa frame that contains only numerical values with no NAs

Comment: I mean to provide code that is really reproducible. If anyone else then you runs `distances = dist(imputedTrainNoQuestions[, 2:5], method = "euclidean") `, they'll get an error, because `imputedTrainNoQuestions` is not in their Workspace. Can you run `dput(imputedTrainNoQuestions[sample(1:5568, size = 50),])` and post the results als text (not as png!)?

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean distance on factor data is *nonsense*.

No wonder it does not work!

Albeit the error will go away if you encode the data as numbers, the results will remain nonsense.

Comment: Well I got rid of the error, there was a mistake in my code and clustered using Euclidean distance and my model works fine.

Comment: It may *run* but the results are not statistically meaningful! Be careful!

Comment: Why not if I am using to cluster a data set that I am then running a logistical regression on?

Comment: Most of the vectors are yes no responses

Comment: Even for binary data, clustering is usually rather meaningless. There are "frequent combinations" of yes/no. But these are not found by regular clustering algorithms. See all the questions here about binary data - it does not "just work". Study the results in detail, and pay attention to what does not make sense (don't just try to "explain" them - you will be seeing things that are not there).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up